# Django : Update column (pick column name dynamically) value

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, sqlalchemy, crud

I want to update a table field by filtering the data and selecting a specific row, in below query "address1" is the field of User table which needs to be updated with value available in variable addr:

**User.objects.filter(user_id=uid).update(address1=addr)**

Above query works fine as I have given column name ="address1" in update option.

But my requirement is I want update field to be dynamic, i.e. it can be address1,address2, address3 (this is stored in a variable) Let's say it is stored in add_field variable then I can't use below as it will try to find add_field column in User table which is not present there:

**User.objects.filter(user_id=uid).update(add_field=addr)**

**Query :** How can I pass field name through variable/dynamically to update option in mentioned line of code or through any other option.

Comment: How you tried unpacking a dictionary with variables?`User.objects.filter(user_id=uid).update(**{add_field:addr})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack a dictionary full of your keyword arguments, like so:

```py
User.objects.filter(user_id=uid).update(**{add_field:addr})
```